# the 5 EMA pine script is giving wrong results

Tags: pine-script

Below is pine script. Why it is marking the highlighted candles as alert if none of the criteria is matching.

[image]

```
ema5 = ta.ema(close, 5 )

plotshape( close[1]>ema5 and low[1]>ema5  , title="AlertC", text="Alert",color=color.new(#FF000D,50), location=location.belowbar, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, textcolor=color.white)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `[]` history reference operator in your condition. That means, you are checking if the previous close and previous low prices are greater than the current `ema5`.

You should look at the ema line on a bar and compare its value with the previous candle's low and close price. Where you marked "incorrect" seems to be correct. The previous candle's low is above the ema line at 09:15.

Comment: Thanks for the review. I am a new to pine scripting. So even if I am using below . Its giving me wrong result. 
My requirement is that the candle which is closing above 5 ema and low is not touching the 3 ema should be flagged as Alert


ema5 = ta.ema(close, 5 )

plotshape( close > ema5 and low>ema5  , title="AlertC", text="Alert",color=color.new(#FF000D,50), location=location.belowbar, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, textcolor=color.white)

Comment: What's the tickerid?

Comment: In trading view we can find it with symbol

NIFTY

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Please edit your question and add another screenshot and show me which bar you think has the wrong signal.